# How often does the secondary DNS for Google's DNS service get used?

Tags: dns, google-dns

I recently noticed that the previous network engineer at our offices had input the Google DNS as : primary 8.8.8.8 and secondary 8.8.8.4.

The secondary DNS had a type in it, and should have been 8.8.4.4

We have been having intermittent problems with network connections to external services, and wondered if this may be the issue.

How does the secondary DNS get used is it purely a fallback or does it get used regularly in tandem with the primary DNS ? If it is purely a fallback does anyone have any info on uptime for Google's primary DNS, i couldn't find a status / uptime page for it.

Comment: It depend on software(your resolver) you using. Resolver may query all DNS servers at once or query them sequentially or use secondary one only as backup if primary DNS not responding. I don't think your issue related to Google, we use their DNS on multi WAN systems to detect unresponsive WAN and for the last 6 years I never saw they failed. Try `MTR` to Google, there could be network issue in a path to 8.8.8.8

Comment: Thanks @Alex ran MTR and got the following, to my un-trained eye it all looks fine, but not 100% sure what to look for, would you mind giving me your point of view on this screenshot from the MTR terminal : http://imgur.com/a/8V60M

Comment: MTR test looks good to me, so it isn't network or google's issue. What DNS are running? Is it Windows domain or it runs on firewall/router?

Comment: @Alex the DNS is set via our Draytek 2860 router, it may be that having the typo in the previously setup DNS was the cause as the MTR test was done once the DNS typo was corrected.. i may change back and test, when i can get some time to "break the network" when no one is working

Comment: Run `MTR` test when you hit your issue, it will help to eliminate at least one point of failure - network issue